# Insert 1 after elements with no count

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file of a structure like this:

```
NH3O
CH4
CHN
C2NOPH3
```

What I was trying to do is to put `1` as a count between the two letters or at the end of the item. Thus, the desired output is:

```
NH3O1
C1H4
C1H1N1
C2N1O1P1H3
```

So far, I was trying something like `sed -e 's/\([A-Z]\)\([A-Z]\)/\11\2/g' -e 's/\([A-Z]\)[[:blank:]]/\11/g'` but that does not work out.

Thanks for any tips

Comment: Are you sure you need `NH3O1` for the first line and no `N1H3O1`? BTW, what is your `sed` version?

Comment: your output is not aligned to your statement requirement(check 1st line of input and corresponding output)

Comment: Ok, in case you have a GNU sed, try `sed -E ':a;s/([[:upper:]])([[:upper:]]|$)/\11\2/;ta' <<< "$s"`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/Wbnfig).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -e ':1' -e 's/\([[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*\)\([[:upper:]]\|$\)/\11\2/' -e 't1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk '{num=split($0,array,"");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){if(array[i]~/^[a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]/ && (array[i]+1)~/^[a-zA-Z]*/){array[i]=array[i]"|"};val=val array[i]};print val;val=""}' Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution here.

```
awk '
{
  num=split($0,array,"")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    if(array[i]~/^[a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]/ && (array[i]+1)~/^[a-zA-Z]*/){
      array[i]=array[i]"|"
    }
    val=val array[i]
  }
  print val
  val=""
}
'   Input_file
```